# Action bar Sherlock crops navigation tab text

Tags: android, tabs, styles, actionbarsherlock

I have implemented sherlock action bar in my application with navigation tabs. I have set the tab text properties to single line using styles attributes. My problem is sherlock action bar crops tab text.for example instead of showing "My Account" it shows only "My".How to show entire tab text , action bar is scrollable.

Comment: set the textview witht as 'fill_parent' and its better if you post ur xml here

Comment: A screenshot would be great

Comment: Please show your code to make the issue visible

Comment: show us your style and how you added tabs in actionbar...

Answer (score 0):

if you have used this way then its show you full name like below

```
Tab tab1 = actionBar
                .newTab()
                .setText("Tab1 - this is detail of main screen")
                .setTabListener(
                        new TabListener<TabFragment>(this, "tab1",
                                TabFragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
```

---

[image]